# subsetting data frame in R with different string

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I want to subset my data (`df1`) by the dataframe 2 (`df2`) by a column1. I have tried using following code.

`df_test <-subset(df1,column1 %in% df2)` but `df_test` comes out empty with just header. which is strange as there is match available in rsid column1. where i am doing it wrong.

here is df1

```
df1

V1     column1   column2
1 frequentist_add_pvalue          rs        rs
2               0.491928 3:146000342 146000342
3                0.05273 3:146000346 146000346
4               0.251884 3:146000581 146000581
5               0.805684 3:146001334 146001334
6               0.252178 3:146001523 146001523
```

and `df2` looks like this.

```
column1 column2

    
    3:146000346 146000346
    3:146000582 146000582
    3:146001335 146001335
    3:146001523 146001523
```

Edit:

```
DF1 = df1[-1,]

dput(DF1[1:7, ])

structure(list(V1 = c("3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3"), V2 = c("146000342", 
"146000346", "146000581", "146001334", "146001523", "146001816", 
"146002091"), V3 = c("3:146000342_G_A", "3:146000346_T_C", "3:146000581_A_T", 
"3:146001334_G_A", "3:146001523_G_A", "3:146001816_A_G", "3:146002091_G_T"
), V4 = c("0.00181023", "0.00553354", "0.0784274", "0.0113356", 
"0.0784285", "0.0912646", "0.00165194"), V5 = c("0.491928", "0.05273", 
"0.251884", "0.805684", "0.252178", "0.252487", "0.570828"), 
    column1 = c("3:146000342", "3:146000346", "3:146000581", 
    "3:146001334", "3:146001523", "3:146001816", "3:146002091"
    ), column2 = c("146000342", "146000346", "146000581", "146001334", 
    "146001523", "146001816", "146002091")), row.names = 2:8, class = "data.frame")

dput(df2[1:2, ])
c("1:100724467", "1:154548946")

> summary(DF1)
      V1                 V2                 V3           
 Length:5464441     Length:5464441     Length:5464441    
 Class :character   Class :character   Class :character  
 Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character  
      V4                 V5              column1         
 Length:5464441     Length:5464441     Length:5464441    
 Class :character   Class :character   Class :character  
 Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character  
   column2         
 Length:5464441    
 Class :character  
 Mode  :character  
> summary(df2)
   column1         
 Length:10633      
 Class :character  
 Mode  :character
```

Comment: Is `rsid` what you are calling `df2`?

Comment: yes exactly. did edit too.

Comment: And does `df1` really have column names `column1` and `column2` but then the first row has values `"frequentist_add_pvalue"`, `rs`, and `rs`? Because that first row being non-numeric can mess up all your column classes. Maybe you need to add `skip = 1` or something when you import `df1` to get it to import properly.

Comment: Since column class issues could be part of the problem, would you share the data with `dput` so we can see class and structure info? `dput(df1[1:6, ])` and `dput(df2[1:4, ])`?

Comment: @GregorThomas thank you for your response. here is dput of my actual data

Comment: please check the edits in question where i have added dput.

Comment: what is `dput[1:2,]` That is incorrect. Unless your df2 is a matrix, you cannot get back a vector. Consider doing `dput(data.frame(df2)`